# Stuck at the "waiting for all target devices to come online" message even though emulator is already running Android Studio 4.2.2

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, apk, emulation

I am having trouble running an .apk file on an emulator in android studio (4.2.2). I am using an M1 chip Mac so I've chosen the S api with arm64 CPU. I cannot seem to get android studio to recognize the emulator is running. I've attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIX1j.png) to show that the emulator is running properly . Any help would be appreciated! I've tried wiping the emulated data as well as reinstalling the emulator. For reference I am using Andoid Emulator version 30.7.5 and Android SDK tools version 30.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping emulator data solved it for me